# First homology group of the complement of a twisted circle in 3-space

Tags: algebraic-topology, knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology, knot-invariants

Let $\mathbb{S}^1_0$ be a circle in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with $n$ number of full twists (rotation by 360). Let $N(\mathbb{S}^1_0)$ be a tubular neighborhood of $\mathbb{S}^1_0$. The first homology group $H_1(\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus N(\mathbb{S}^1_0))=\mathbb{Z}$. Assume that the loop in $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus N(\mathbb{S}^1_0)$ that is identified to $\mathbb{S}^1_0$ is $[1]$ or $[0]$ in $H_1(\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus N(\mathbb{S}^1_0))$.

Let $\mathbb{S}^1_1$ be a circle in $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus N(\mathbb{S}^1_0)$ with $n+1$ number of full twists. How to describe this circle $\mathbb{S}^1_1$ in $H_1(\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus N(\mathbb{S}^1_0))$?

Comment: What does the "number of full twists" mean? Is this circle means to be a knot? In any case this homology class you seek will depend on the embedding of both circles into $\Bbb R^3$ (it is essentially the linking number).

Comment: We can think of the circle $\mathbb{S}^1_0$ as a torus-knot (1,n) embedded in a torus so that we can not untwist it. From your comment Lord Shark, I see that $[\mathbb{S}^1_1]$ in  homology of the complement of $\mathbb{S}^1_0$ is the linking number between the torus knots (1,n) and (1,n+1), isn't it? What is that, is it $\pm 1$?

Answer (score 1):

It is just the definition of the linking number $\text{lk}(K_0,K_1)=n+1$.

Comment: @user113715 You have to choose the best answer to close questions.